# How to prove that the set of Real numbers is infinite

Tags: functions

If there exists a 1-1 correspondence between a set S and a proper subset of itself, the set S is said to be infinite.Using this, prove that the set of Real numbers is infinite.

The above is a homework question I got. I am unable to proceed further.

However, I try to move forward by using the below approach.

Let us consider a function

$f : [0,1] \to (0,1)$

If I somehow win to prove that there exists a bijection between such a function, I think I can answer my question.But how do I go forward from here?

Comment: My suggestion to you is to consider the arctan function. Alternatively I suggest you try constructing bijections between intervals of the same type, such as from $[0,1] $ onto $[0,2]$ (so either both closed or both open). This is much simpler than constructing a bijection between closed and open intervals

Comment: So, your approach is to find a bijection between a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ (in this case $[0, 1]$), and a sub-subset (in this case, $(0, 1)$)? This will indeed prove that $[0, 1]$ is infinite, and hence $\Bbb{R}$ is too, as it contains $[0, 1]$. However, I would think that showing the natural numbers are infinite would be easier?

Comment: It might also be easier to show a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $(-x,x)$ for some $x>0$. Convenient choices include $x=\pi$ or $x=1$. Trying to show a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ rules out a lot of simple ways to deal with your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to go to $[0,1] \to (0,1)$, where finding that function is trickier, and even then you would have to either find a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and one of those sets or argue that if $X$ has an infinite set, then $X$ itself is infinite.

Let's try it directly on the real numbers!

**Hint**: Asymptotes are your friends

> $arctan$ and $exp$ offer great examples.

A function represented by this graph maps all the real numbers into the positives, while still being injective

[image]

Similarly, a function represented by this graph maps all the real numbers into an interval:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting this :(

Comment: @AayushUpadhyaya You only need to find an example of a function (in the real numbers) that is bijective but does not take all real values. Functions with horizontal asymptotes often help here, as the graph never goes above/below them but injectivity is not lost

Comment: @David- Oh you meant that $e^x$ function? Yeah that's a very good example.Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @AayushUpadhyaya Yes! Also $arctan$ makes quite a good one, since it makes the bijection to a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ But there are of course many others

Answer (score 6):

Here is another example:
$$f(x):=\left\{\eqalign{x\quad&\qquad(x\leq0)\cr x+1&\qquad(x>0)\cr}\right.\quad.$$